# iPhone 3.2 Base64 Encoding

Tags: iphone, authentication, encoding, base64

I'm adding a Basic HTTP Authorisation Header into a request but need to encode the authString to Base64. For info, I can't use didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge due to excessive 401 errors being produced.

The code below works fine in iOS 4.2 but doesn't work on iOS 3.2 (and I want to support this).

`NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", user, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding];`

```
authString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@", authString];

NSMutableURLRequest* request =
[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url 
                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                         timeoutInterval: 30];

[request setValue: authString forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

In the first line of my code above I get the warning that NSData will not respond to 'base64Encoding'.

So I've downloaded the custom class NSData+Base64 from here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

But......I don't know how to use this class to convert my NSString (authString). Please help?!

I think the following line of code should fix:

`NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", user, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];`

but I get following message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData base64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Have I missed an Import or something?

P.S. This is my first question on here, so go easy on me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` has a `-dataUsingEncoding:` method which you can use to convert `NSString` instances to `NSData` instances. After that, you can use MG's Base64 category.

Comment: Do you mean change this line of code to something like this?
NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", user, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataFromBase64String];
or like this
NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", user, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];

Comment: FIXED IT! I had one project referencing another. I couldn't get it to work in the secondary project but when I put #import "NSData+Base64.h" in the base project app Prefix header file (.pch) and added the class to the base project and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the category to use the BASE64Encoding method in your NSData class?? here i made a tutorial to easy create categories, which basically are modifications of an existing class, in this case NSData: http://www.donttouchmycode.com/objective-c-class/extending-an-existing-class-with-categories i hope this can help you.